# so what's the order of ops here regarding the parameters?

Tags: java, netbeans, parameters, constructor

```
public class HelloStack{

    private String myName;
    private int myAge;
    private String myHeritage;

    HelloStack(String myName, int myAge, String myHeritage){
        this.myName = myName;
        this.myAge = myAge;
        this.myHeritage = myHeritage;
    }
```

Then in my `main()` I create an object:

```
HelloStack hiGuys = new HelloStack("joseph", 89, "indian");
```

If my understanding is correct on the role of parameters here, I'm passing the values from `hiGuys` into the constructor `Hellostack`, and then they're actually initialized in the constructor when the compiler runs through?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum, it is more similar to a wiki. Try to make questions in a way that make them useful for further people. In your case, you could reword the question like: "What is the order of initialization of class properties in the constructor".

Answer (score 1):

No. First, you create the HelloStack object:

```
new HelloStack("joseph", 89, "indian");
```

Then a few things happen with object loading and instantiation that aren't relevant. The next thing is that the thread enters the constructor, calls an implicit `super()` constructor, and then sets the fields one at a time:

```
    this.myName = myName;
    this.myAge = myAge;
    this.myHeritage = myHeritage;
```

Then the constructor "returns" the new object. That object is assigned to your `hiGuys` variable.

```
HelloStack hiGuys =
```

So now hiGuys has a single value - that new object.